# Print out only failed tasks - Ansible

Tags: ansible

I have created an Ansible playbook which just checks the connection to target hosts on a specific port.
Here is my playbook

```
- name: ACL check to target machines.
  hosts: all
  gather_facts: False

  vars:

    target_hosts:
      - server1 18089
      - server1 8089
      - server1 18000

  tasks:
    - name: execute the command
      command: "nc -vz {{ item }}"
      with_items: "{{ target_hosts }}"
```

The output i get when i execute the playbook contains both changed(success) and failed.

In real scenario i have many number of target hosts, & my output is very large.

What i wanted here is, i want to have final report at bottom which shows only list of all failed connections between source and target.

Thanks

Comment: Please don't post screenshots of text; it makes the question less searchable and in general increases the effort required to read a question

Answer (score 3):

> i want to have final report at bottom which shows only list of all failed connections between source and target

I believe the knob you are looking for is [stdout callback plugins](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/plugins/callback.html). While I don't see one that does *exactly* as you wish, there are two of them that seem like they may get you close:

The [actionable](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/plugins/callback/actionable.html) one claims it will only emit Failed and Changed events:

```
$ ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=actionable ansible-playbook ...
```

Then, moving up the complexity ladder, the [json](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.6/plugins/callback/json.html) one will, as its name implies, emit a record of the steps in JSON, allowing you to filter the output for *exactly* what you want (`.failed` is a boolean on each task that indicates just that):

```
$ ANSIBLE_STDOUT_CALLBACK=json ansible-playbook ...
```

Then, as the "plugins" part implies, if you were so inclined you could also implement your own that does **exactly** what you want; there are [a lot of examples](https://github.com/ansible/ansible/tree/v2.6.3/lib/ansible/plugins/callback) provided, in addition to the docs.

Answer (score 2):

The answer by @mdaniel on 2018 Aug 18 is unfortunately no longer correct as the 'actionable' callback has been removed:

```
community.general.actionable has been removed. Use the 'default' callback plugin with 'display_skipped_hosts = no' and 'display_ok_hosts = no' options. This feature was removed from community.general in version 2.0.0. Please update your playbooks.
```

We are to use the [default callback](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/default_callback.html?highlight=display_ok_hosts) with some parameters instead.

I used this in my ansible.cfg

```
stdout_callback = default
display_skipped_hosts = no
display_ok_hosts = no
```

It worked for the live output but still showed all the ok and skipped hosts in the summary at the end.

Also, `$ DISPLAY_SKIPPED_HOSTS=no DISPLAY_OK_HOSTS=no ansible-playbook ...` didn't seem to work which is unfortunate because I prefer the `yaml` callback normally and only occasionally want to override this with the above.

Comment: If you prefix Ansible settings with `ANSIBLE_`. So: `ANSIBLE_DISPLAY_SKIPPED_HOSTS=no`  and `ANSIBLE_DISPLAY_OK_HOSTS=no` they will work. This also applies to other settings.

Answer (score 0):

I have a similar playbook and want the same list of failed connection, what I do is:

- Save the output command `register: nc`
- Add the `ignore_errors: true`
- In the debug part show the ok and failed connections asking for the return code.

My playbook:

```
---
  - name: test-connection
    gather_facts: false
    hosts: "{{ group_hosts }}"
    tasks:
      - name: test connection 
        shell: "nc -w 5 -zv {{ inventory_hostname }} {{ listen_port }}"
        register: nc
        ignore_errors: true

      - name: ok connections
        debug: var=nc.stderr
        when: "nc.rc == 0"

      - name: failed connections
        debug: var=nc.stderr
        when: "nc.rc != 0"
```

An output example for the failed connections:

```
TASK [failed connections] **********************************************************************************************
ok: [10.1.2.100] => {
    "nc.stderr": "nc: connect to 10.1.2.100 port 22 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress"
}
ok: [10.1.2.101] => {
    "nc.stderr": "nc: connect to 10.1.2.101 port 22 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress"
}
ok: [10.1.2.102] => {
    "nc.stderr": "nc: connect to 10.1.2.102 port 22 (tcp) timed out: Operation now in progress"
```